# Matlab. Storing 2D arrays within 3D arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have defined the following 2D function,

```
Ngrid = 100;
h     = 1/(Ngrid-1);
x     = 0:h:1;
y     = 0:h:1;
[x y] = meshgrid(x,y);
f = exp(-((1-x).^2)./0.45)
```

and I want to store this function within the 3D array "c",along the "T" dimension,

```
k    = 0.001;
Tend = 1; 
T    = 0:k:Tend;
c    = zeros(length(T),length(x),length(y));
```

What I have tried is,

```
c(1:end,:,:) = f;
```

but it does not work. ¿Any idea of how can I store the same function within this 3D array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your function `f` depends only on `x` (no `y`).. is that really a 2d function?

Comment: What does `it does not work` mean?

Comment: Yes, it is a 100x100 array, due to x is generated by meshgrid. Also, if you do surf(f) is a 2D function, although it is independant of the y coordinate. What I want to do is to store this 100x100 array at every position of c (along T).

Comment: The error I get is the typical "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.". Sorry, I am completely new at 2D and 3D models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscript dimension mismatch is because you are trying to squeeze `100 * 100` elements into a `1001 x 100 x 100` matrix.

You could do this assignment the following way:

```
c(1,:,:) = f;
c(2,:,:) = f;
...
c(1001,:,:) = f;
```

But you can accomplish the same thing using [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

```
c = repmat(reshape(f, [1, size(f)]), [numel(T), 1 1]);
```

Or [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
c = bsxfun(@plus, zeros(numel(T), 1), reshape(f, [1, size(f)]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Now the code works; I understand my mistake.